# Function pointer reference

Tags: c++, pointers

I need to hook 10/20 functions like these:

```
static void* __cdecl HookSoundFileSubBZR(char *FileName, int a2, int a3, int a4);


 __declspec(naked)  void HookSoundFileSub_BZCC_Asm(char  *Src, int pedx, int 
    
    a3, int a4, int a5, int a6);
    
 static BOOL HookSoundFileSubWCP(int a1, DWORD *a2, DWORD *a3, int a4, char a5, int a6);
```

and I use this code:

```
switch (int iD)
{
case 1

    DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHook, &HookSoundFileSubBZR);

case 2
   DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHook, &HookSoundFileSub_BZCC_Asm);

case 3
   DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHook, &HookSoundFileSubWCP);
.....
}
```

but I like to not repeat x times "DetourAttach" and I like do to something like this:

```
switch (int iD)
{
case 1

    HookFunction = &HookSoundFileSubBZR;

case 2
    HookFunction = &HookSoundFileSub_BZCC_Asm;

case 3
   HookFunction = &HookSoundFileSubWCP;
.....
}

DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHook, &HookFunction);
```

I ask if there is a easy way to do this becouse is more flexible.

Thanks !!

Update here the detour parameters:

```
LONG WINAPI DetourAttach(_Inout_ PVOID *ppPointer,
                         _In_ PVOID pDetour);
```

Comment: Sounds all a bit mysterious and seems to my like an XY-problem. What you want to achieve? It looks a bit like implementing vtable by hand :-)

Comment: I explain better, I need to hook 10/20 functions and If possible I like to avoid to write 10/20 times  "DetourAttach" and "DetourDetach".

Comment: What is the function definition of DetourAttach( type_1 arg_1, type_2 arg_2){....}. Giving this, it may be put as a constructor of a class.

Comment: thanks  ytlu , to be honest I don't have too much experience in c++ can you post an example ? I have updated the question.

Comment: Post [mcve] code.  The pseudo code above isn't very illuminating.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Just declare `PVOID HookFunction;` and then `HookFunction = (PVOID)HookSoundFileSubBZR;` etc. (But you want `HookFunction` in the `DetourAttach` call, not `&HookFunction`.)

Comment: You only provide us some obscure solutions but not the underlying problem! I believe, you did some hacks here and I believe you do not need them! Again: What is the problem you want to solve! Manually assign function pointers via ids with all the fully compiler and os dependent non portable specialties looks horrible! Advice: Start writing portable code :-) I miss c++ in your example at all. All the C-style hacks nearly on assembler level... can't be the right way I believe. As long we did not know what you want to do, I vote to close!

Comment: TonyK: thank you !! now I try and I let you known.

Comment: Klaus: I explain what the project do. It is a general DLL that add the Force Feedback support to some game. Each function is a hook to single game. In short switch the game ID and choose the function to pass to DetourAttach. Some functions contain assembly but I don't think is important. Now I try the solution of TonyK  to see if work ...

Comment: TonyK: your solution is very easy and work perfectly. If you answer the question I will accept. Many thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare

```
PVOID HookFunction;
```

and then

```
HookFunction = (PVOID)HookSoundFileSubBZR;
```

etc. (But you want `HookFunction` in the `DetourAttach` call, not `&HookFunction`.)